# Classic ASP - ASPPDF how to create a pdf document with multiple pages and 1 page template

Tags: pdf, asp-classic, pdf-generation

its possible to create a new document with multiples pages - based in a PDF Template with ONE page only?

Its a member list - with name, ID and signature. I had a template for 1 page. but if the classroom have many members I can have a lots of pages..

Im trying, but I only create new docs with one page..

I dont know how I can create page 2, 3.. with the same template.. (of course, if its possible..)

I think this is the easiest way to make the docs..

tks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possile and you can do it easily. Have a look at [Document Stitching](http://www.asppdf.com/manual_12.html#12_2).

```vb
Dim objPDF
Set objPDF = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Pdf")

Dim binTplDoc 'to hold template pdf document's binary content

With objPDF.OpenDocument(Server.MapPath("1-page-template.pdf"))
    binTplDoc = .SaveToMemory
    .Close
End With

Dim MultiPageDoc
Set MultiPageDoc = objPDF.CreateDocument 'a blank document
    'add the same document several times
    MultiPageDoc.AppendDocument objPDF.OpenDocumentBinary(binTplDoc)
    'do something with MultiPageDoc.Pages(0)
    MultiPageDoc.AppendDocument objPDF.OpenDocumentBinary(binTplDoc)
    'do something with MultiPageDoc.Pages(1)
    '..
```